# MySQL data structure advice needed

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database-design, full-text-search

I need some advice regarding how to organize my data for effective and fast text search.

### Background

I have an application (in PHP) where the user can organize articles and dynamically create forms and fields for that purpose. Meaning that one article can for example have Type,Brand,Color attributes and another article can for example have Type,Material,Color,Content as attributes.
The user can basically create as many attributes he likes...

Then I need to be able to search and sort among these "unknown" attributes.
I also need to be able to read back all the attributes in the case the user want to edit the article.

### My solution

My first idea (and so far only idea) is to encode all the attributes into a single `TEXT` field with a `FULLTEXT` index (needs to be MyISAM to work), like:

```
__Type="3",__Brand="Nokia",__Color="6"
__Type="2",__Material="7",Color="2",Content="MP3 Player,2 Apples, 1 book: Larry King"
```

The attributes would get a prefix and/or postfix to not be confused with the values in the attributes. Or serialize the attributes with JSON.

Then I can build a query based on the selected attributes like:

```
SELECT * FROM Articles a
WHERE Attribute LIKE '%__TYPE="2"%'
AND Attribute LIKE '%__Color="2"%'
```

If an attribute is empty, it will not be included and this makes it possible to include a search on all articles that has a specific attribute set, regardless of its value.

### Problem

Problem or not, what I'm worried about is the search performance when the database is filled with thousands of articles.

Another problem would also be to search for a particular word inside a specific attribute, such as:

Content="MP3 Player,2 Apples, 1 book: Larry King"

Let's say I only want to get rows where the attribute Content have the phrase "Larry King" somewhere. I don't think I can do that in the same SQL question without getting a match on all rows that has "Larry King" somewhere.

I'm open for any kind of suggestion/discussion regarding what tables,fields and relations I should create to achieve the goals explained.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it type=3 has always brand and color; type=2 always: material, color, content?

Comment: There will always be a "root" attribute, but attributes can be arranged as a tree on many levels, so the "Type" here might end up with different set/forms of attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to be often searching on the value of a particular attribute, why not make those attributes their own columns in the table? Or if you want a more flexible structure, make a second table like:

```
CREATE TABLE attributes (
 my_id int unsigned not null default 0,
 attribute_key varchar(255) not null default '',
 attribute_value varchar(255) not null default '',
 KEY (my_id),
 KEY (attribute_key),
 KEY (attribute_value)
);
```

In this case, the `my_id` field is the primary key of your main table. So rather than serializing a string like:

```
__Type="2",__Material="7",Color="2",Content="MP3 Player,2 Apples, 1 book: Larry King"
```

You would instead create some rows like:

```
INSERT INTO attributes VALUES (1, 'Type', '2');
INSERT INTO attributes VALUES (1, 'Color', '2');
INSERT INTO attributes VALUES (1, 'Content', 'MP3 Player,2 Apples, 1 book: Larry King');
```

And then you would formulate your search query like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
LEFT JOIN attributes ON mytable.my_id = attributes.my_id 
WHERE attributes.attribute_key = 'Type' AND attributes.attribute_value = '2';
```

This does not precisely solve the second problem of your question, but it will perform far, far better than doing a full text search across thousands of rows. You can of course then add a `FULLTEXT` index on the `attribute_value` field as well to query it for text fragments like your "Larry King" example.

Comment: +1 A very good idea, I need to give it some toughs to see if it will cover all my needs. I'm still open for more suggestions...

Comment: @futureal But the table "attributes" would be huge, like 5 or 8 times bigger then the actual article table. Is this approach still winning performance over my original thought?

Comment: Yes, very much so. Having a lot of rows is not a problem if they are properly indexed. If you have `n` rows in the main table and you run a query on a particular attribute, it will still only be examining `n` rows (at most). It will only look at the subset of data that is relevant to the query.

Comment: I find you solution to be the best option here, Thank you!

Comment: No problem -- this is actually a pretty standard SQL design pattern so it is good to know and practice with. Good luck! :)

Comment: @futureal A thought... It seems like the attributes will be mainnly of two types: Numerical only and Text. Would I gain anything of having two Attribute tables, one for strictly integers (such as color or type) where the integer is an ID in a string table. With this approach I could make joins to get the textual value in the same question when displaying an article. I guess it is only comes down to what table to search in. I guess a specifib index numerical index is more effective.

Comment: Seems like the solutions - however when pulling data I will use GROUP_CONCAT - it will combine all attributes in 1 field (way how you wanted) in 1 record

Comment: @Joanna I have organized the tables in a different way and use a UNION ALL to pull all data together. This continues in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668747/mysql-merging-two-fields-from-two-tables-into-one-field-in-result-set