# MySQL Merging Two fields from two tables into one field in result set

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Thank you for all the help I have received here and yet, here I'm with a complementary question.

### Setup

I have 3 relevant tabels in MySQL:

```
STRINGVALUES
ID   ItemID   Key    Value
1    1        Note   My note book is electronica

INTEGERVALUES
ID   ItemID Key    Value
1    1      Color  2
2    1      Type   4

STRINGS
ID   Value
1    Stone
2    Red
3    Blue
4    Phone
```

Other fields has been removed to only show what is relevant.
ItemID is the identifier for an Article. In this case I have only entered information for Article 1 (ItemID=1)

The INTEGERVALUES table uses the `Value` as an ID to lookup a value in the STRINGS table (hence a separate table with only integers). The strings table also have support for multiple languages while StringValues are data entered by users.

### Desired result

The SQL query I have now looks like this:

```
SELECT i.*, ai.Key, ai.Value,
(SELECT s.Value FROM Strings s WHERE ai.Value=s.StringID) sValue,
(SELECT ats.Value FROM attributestrings ats WHERE ats.ItemID=i.ItemID) sValue
FROM items i
INNER JOIN AttributeIntegers ai ON i.ItemID=ai.ItemID
WHERE i.ID = 1
```

This gives me the relevant result

```
ItemID Key    Value  sValue  sValue
1      Color  2      Red     My note book is electronica
1      Type   4      Phone   My note book is electronica
```

What I want is this result:

```
ItemID Key    Value  sValue
1      Color  2      Red
1      Type   4      Phone
1      Note   Null   My note book is electronica
```

I'm trying to read up on UNION but I don't know if it is the right answer...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  itemid, key, iv.value, s.value AS svalue
        FROM    integervalues iv
        JOIN    strings s
        ON      s.id = iv.value
        WHERE   iv.itemid = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  itemid, key, NULL, value
        FROM    stringvalues sv
        WHERE   sv.itemid = 1
        ) vals
JOIN    items i
ON      i.id = vals.itemid
```

Comment: This works well if I exclude the Items table. But I still need the i.* from Items i as well. Is there a way to limit the union to a subset of fields/tables? I would need something like ´SELECT i.*, key, iv.value, s.value AS svalue´ in the first Select statement. I tried to make your whole query as a subquery, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Max: see the post update. Do you really need duplicates of `i.*` in each record?

Comment: Well I see your point, but I need the information from i.* as well. Are you suggesting two separated SQL queries?

Comment: Is there not a way to map the Union fields, field by field so I can have different number of fields in the SELECT statements?

Comment: @Max: a single resultset can only have a fixed number of records. Yes, it would be better to query `items` first to get one record, then get all values in a separate query. You can write a stored procedure which would return two recordsets to avoid multiple roundtrips to the server.

Comment: I got it now, thanks! Good Idea with a stored proc. How do I handle two record sets returned in PHP?

Comment: @Max: use `mysqli_multi_query` and `mysqli_next_result`. This is only available in `mysqli` extension, though, not `mysql`.

Comment: Okay, well I'm using MySQL but I will investigate. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT i.*, ai.Key, ai.Value,
(SELECT s.Value FROM Strings s WHERE ai.Value=s.StringID) sValue,
(SELECT ats.Value FROM attributestrings ats WHERE ats.ItemID=i.ItemID) sValue
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN AttributeIntegers ai ON i.ItemID=ai.ItemID
WHERE i.ID = 1
```

And for merging 2 fields into one use CONCAT:

```
SELECT CONCAT('My field1 data', ', ',  'My field2 data');
```

results in :

```
"My field1 data, My field2 data"
```

Comment: This is not the result I'm looking for. They mixed on the same row, in my example above they slide in as a new row with the same fields.

Comment: @Max Kielland: Sorry Max, I totally did not understand your question.

Comment: Well, I guess the Headline was a bit missleading ;) Thank you for trying.